# Matplotlib to plot path taken in 2d grid that wraps round the edges

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D 32 x 32 toroidal grid world.  An ant can walk around the world, when reaching an edge, the ant wraps round to the other side of the world.  When I plot this path using Matplotlib:

```
path = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (31, 3), (31, 2), (31, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2),\
    (31, 2), (30, 2), (30, 3), (30, 4), (30, 5), (29, 5)]
ys_path, xs_path = np.array(path).T
axes.plot(xs_path, ys_path, '-')
```

I get horizontal and vertical lines whenever the ant wraps round to the other side.  Any idea how I can not connect the points through the middle of the world?  In the image, the red circles are all the squares the ant has passed over.

If the absolute value of the difference between consecutive is 31, then insert (np.nan, np.nan) at that position.... but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
self.path excerpt:
array([[  0,   1],
       [  0,   1],
       [ 31,   0],  # at this point in path insert a np.nan tuple
       [  0,  -1],
       [  0,  -1],
       [-31,   0],
       [  0,   1],
       [ 31,   0],
       [ -1,   0],
       [  0,   1],
       [  0,   1],
       [  0,   1],
       [ -1,   0]])

path = np.array(self.path, dtype=np.float)
path = np.insert(path, 
np.nonzero(np.abs(np.diff(path, axis=0)) > 1)[0] + 1, np.nan, axis=0)

ys_path, xs_path = np.array(path).T  #flip i and j for coordinate system
axes.plot(xs_path+0.5, ys_path+0.5, '-') # centre in middle of square
```

This does what we want it to and it inserts a NaN tuple in the path array, Genius!

Comment: try inserting `np.nan` values into your arrays

Comment: The data is a list of tuples, converted to an ndarray of xs and ys.  Inserting a NAN will remove a point from the path. I was thinking I need to look at the difference between consecutive points, but then not sure how to tell plot not to join those points.

Comment: I'm not saying you should replace anything. I'm saying you should inject them between e.g., a right-most coordinate immediately followed by a left-most coordinate

Comment: @PaulH Thanks, I get what you're saying, just not sure how to implement it.  I've added some sample data, I'll try some things and update the question with my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html). It does exactly what you want. You can get the indices of the locations where [`diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) returns something other than +/-1 with [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html). The first return value will be the row indices, regardless of which direction the break occurs in. The indices in the diff have to be incremented by one since `insert` operates with the assumption that you are specifying the index after the insertion point:

```
path = np.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (31, 3), (31, 2), (31, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2),
                 (31, 2), (30, 2), (30, 3), (30, 4), (30, 5), (29, 5)], dtype=np.float)
delta = np.diff(path, axis=0)
mask = (np.abs(delta) > 1)
row_indices = np.nonzero(mask)[0]
row_indices += 1
path = np.insert(path, row_indices, np.nan, axis=0)

...

axes.plot(*path.T, '-')
```

This code saves a temporary variable for each step to make it a bit easier to follow. You can of course turn it into a one-liner or something in between depending on your needs and aesthetic preferences:

```
path = np.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (31, 3), (31, 2), (31, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2),
                 (31, 2), (30, 2), (30, 3), (30, 4), (30, 5), (29, 5)], dtype=np.float)
path = np.insert(path, np.nonzero(np.abs(np.diff(path, axis=0)) > 1)[0] + 1, np.nan, axis=0)

...

axes.plot(*path.T, '-')
```

Depending on how you plan to use `path` later, it may not be necessary to split it an permanently transpose it at all. You can use parameter expansion to pass it as two separate arrays to `axes.plot`.

Comment: After moving a paren closing the the np.abs, everything works like a charm!  Thank you @Mad Physicist!

Comment: @BlueShrapnel. Feel free to make the edit in here directly. The one liner version was an afterthought, and untested.

Comment: @BlueShrapnel. Nvm. I found and corrected the error. Thanks for the catch.